# xpath expression dependent upon siblings

Tags: xslt, xpath, xquery

```
<a id ="1">
...<c>
......<b/>
......<f/>
......<b/>
......<f/>
...</c>
</a>
<a id="2">
...<c>
......<b/>
......<f/>
......<f/>
...</c>
</a>
```

If any elem b is followed by two or more f elements in order, return node a. I prefer straight XPath 2.0 solution, if possible. What xpath will get me a2 but not a1? I have tried following siblings, position, and such, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

With XPath 1.0:

```
a[.//b[following-sibling::*[1]/self::f and following-sibling::*[2]/self::f]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
//a[.//b/following-sibling::*[1][self::f]/following-sibling::*[1][self::f]]
```

This says to find the a element that contains a b element, which is immediately followed by a f element, which is immediately followed by a f element.

Comment: Yes..that's the algorithm I also followed.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like below will work using **XPATH 1.0**:

```
//b[following-sibling::*[
       position()=1 and self::f
       and
       ./following-sibling::*[
                                position()= 1 and self::f
                             ]
                        ]
   ]/ancestor::a[1]
```

**output**

```
<a id="2">
...<c>
......<b/>
......<f/>
......<f/>
...</c>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get a2 using this :

```
       //a[@id=2]
```

just by using the id attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this:

```
/a//c[f/following-sibling::*[1] = f]
```

Comment: similar to this ?
//a[.//b/following-sibling::*[1][self::f]/following-sibling::*[1][self::f]]